# Hyperledger Iroha: Can't generate genesis-block

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-iroha

I am trying to generate a new genesis-block in **Hyperledger Iroha** as it is suggested in

https://iroha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/index.html#starting-iroha-node
and

https://hyperledger.github.io/iroha-api/#create-genesis-block

but unfortunately I can't do it because I am always getting the same error message.

```
$ cat peer.list 
localhost:10001
$ ./iroha-cli --genesis_block --peers_address peer.list
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::out_of_range> >'
what():  bimap<>: invalid key
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am receiving this error both on my local machine where I had compiled Iroha from scratch using the source code, as well as within an Iroha container.
I think I have the correct dependencies, otherwise I would have not been able to build Iroha from scratch. Also, note that I can start *irohad* correctly by using the configuration example from https://iroha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/index.html#launching-iroha-daemon.

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not a programming problem. It just means that you're looking for something in the map that isn't there. That's an application error.

Comment: I believe this is an Hyperledger Iroha problem

Answer (score 3):

There was, indeed, a bug affecting the permissions needed to generate a block. It is fixed now and should not occur: https://github.com/hyperledger/iroha/pull/1351

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in the development of hyperledger iroha, see here: https://github.com/hyperledger/iroha/issues/1362.
It arises when iroha is compiled with Ansible Playbook.
Try to uninstall Ansible from your system and re-compile iroha and you shouldn't encounter the same error.
Obviously this is just a work around, and you won't be able to take advantage of the ansible capabilities.